# Reading values from a graph in Python

Tags: python, plot

I'm currently trying to plot data from a SPICE simulation in python. I have succeed in plotting the information but now I require to extract values from specific points, say for example I would like to find the `x` value for a given `y` or vice versa.

```
pylab.figure(1)
pylab.title('NMOS')
pylab.semilogy(row.ngm_id[81*0:81*1],row.nidw[81*0:81*1],label='L = 0.35u')
pylab.xlabel('gm/ID [S/A]',fontsize=20)
pylab.ylabel('ID/W [A/m]',fontsize=20)
pylab.legend()
pylab.grid()
pylab.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best way would be to get the data before trying to plot them, but if you canìt find any other way, you can get back the data from the line object obtained from the plot:

```
# other commands
lines = pylab.semilogy(...)
#other commands
x,y = lines[0].get_data()
```

Comment: You are right, thanks. It is better to get the data without having to generate a figure. I used the function eval_at(a.b,val) from the wavemeas library.